# Help understanding a paragraph in Kadanes book Principles of uncertainty.

Tags: probability-theory

> Consider two infinite sequences of indicators of events, $s_1$ and
>   $s_2$ , with respective relative frequencies $l_1$ and $l_2$, where
>   $l_1=l_2$. Let $A$ be the indicator of an event not an element of
>   $s_1$ or $s_2$ . Consider new sequences $s^\prime_1 = (A, s_1 )$ and
>   $s^\prime_2 = (A, s_2 )$. These sequences have relative frequencies
>   $l_1$ and $l_2$ , respectively. Hence within this theory the event A
>   does not have a well-defined probability.

Quote is from page 76/77.

I am confused in how to understand $s_i$. What does it mean that $A$ is not an element of $s_1$ or $s_2$?

It also says

> ...Let $A$ be the indicator of an event not an element of not an element of $s_1$ or $s_2$.

What does this mean? $s_i$ are supposed to be sequences of of indicators, not events. So how do the new sequences look like, namely $s^\prime_i$? Also, why do they have the same relative frequencies $l_i$.

Please help me understand the text...